# захват объекта с веб-камеры и внесение данных в строку в браузере

Tags: java, web-camera

Всем доброго времени суток! 
помогите найти информацию, как заставить вебкамеру с планшета(Android) распознать на весах цифры, и вносить эти данные в строку для заполнения этих самых данных! 
то есть, при наведении камеры на циферблат весов, чтоб она могла распознать эти самые цифры и внести данные в соответствующую сроку и к тому же фото товара должна тоже сохраняться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача не тривиальная и сложная. Думаю надо смотреть в сторону openCV библиотеки, изучать и обучать Ее